# How to retain selected value of dropdown when redirecting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm currently trying to make dropdown of date to filter data. The filtering process itself working fine but I want to retain the selected date. Based on my reading you can use old helper to retain the data but it does not work for me. I'm still new using laravel.

[image: 1]

Below are my code:

(view)

```
@props(['expense'])

<x-card>
    <header class="text-center">
        <h2 class="text-3xl font-bold uppercase mb-1">
            Daily Report
        </h2>
    </header>
    <div>
        <h3 class="text-xl">
            <div>

                <form method="GET" action="/">
                    <label for="date">Daily expense on:</label>
                    <input class="border border-black rounded p-2" type="date" id="date" name="date" value="{{old('date')}}" />
                    <input class="bg-laravel text-white rounded py-2 px-4 hover:bg-black" type="submit" />
                </form>
                
                @unless(count($expense) == 0)
                
                @foreach($expense as $data)
                <li>{{$data->category}} ${{$data->amount}}</li>
                @endforeach

                @else
                <p>No expenses found</p>
                @endunless

            </div>
        </h3>
    </div>
</x-card>
```

(controller)

```
public function index() {
        return view('expenses.index', [
            'expenses' => Expense::latest()->filter(request(['date']))->get()
        ]);
    }
```

Hope my explanation is clear. Please inform me if it's not.

Comment: Show your Controller; how are you doing your redirect? Are you using the `->withInput()` method on your redirect? `old()` only works in some cases, which you may or may not be doing here, but you omitted your code for some reason...

Comment: You can use sessions to set and get data across pages, checkout the link below.


https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/session#storing-data

Comment: What are you using for the frontend? Plain blade? What's the <x-card> component come from?